# Brownie doesnt compile but says it did

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

if i run `brownie compile` i get
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documenten\demo\build\contracts

but its not in there